# How to test on Chainweaver without deploying to testnet or mainnet

Tags: pact

I want to use some external modules in my contract (using Chainweaver), but I don't understand how to do it without deploying.

E.g. I would like to try `coin.transfer` or `kip.poly-fungible-v2`

From REPL I get the error `cannot resolve coin.transfer` or `Module kip.poly-fungible-v2 not found`

Answer (score 1):

If testing in REPL, you need to load the modules you want to call locally into REPL.
This pretty much invovles copy/pasting the files and loading them in

Comment: ok, now the error is gone, but when I try to call some fun with ADMIN capability I receive the error "with-read: row not found"
could you explain the next steps better? like create an account in repl